# TCPDF Header and Top Margin on fist page only then no header and different top margin on remaining pages

Tags: tcpdf

I am using tcpdf to generate a pdf. I only want the header to appear on the first page and have it so that it does not appear on the remaining pages. However, I would like the top margin of the remaining pages shifted up since there is no header on those pages.

I'm using MYPDF to extend TCPDF to customize the header to only show on the first page.

```html
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

 //Page header

      public function Header() {
            if (count($this->pages) === 1) { // Do this only on the first page
                $html .= 'header text';
            }

            $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
        }
        }
        
       
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 25, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(10);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 20);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
 $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('droidsansfallback', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->resetColumns();
$pdf->setEqualColumns(3, 57);  // KEY PART -  number of cols and width
$pdf->selectColumn();                          
      $content = '';  
      $content .= '  

      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
         
      ';  
      $content .= fetch_data();  
      $content .= '</table>';  
      $pdf->writeHTML($content);  
      $pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this worked for me:

```
public function Header() {
    if ($this->page == 1) {
        $html .= 'header text';
        $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
    } else {
        $this->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 10, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    }
}
```

Only write the header HTML on the first page, then change the margins for the other pages.